# Problems on solving LeetCode #1 : got multiple values for an argument

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the #1 question in LeetCode, Two Sum, with bisection method. But I encountered an error, which said `got multiple values for argument \`array``. How can I solve this error ? And please tell me why it occurs, so next time I can avoid making the same mistake. Thanks ahead.

The original question is as follows.

[image: LeetCode #1 Two Sum]

My codes are as follows.

```py
#
# @lc app=leetcode.cn id=1 lang=python3
#
# [1] 两数之和
#
# @lc code=start
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

        # Copy the original list and sort it, so I can get the index of answer from the original
        # list after I use a sorted list to find the answer.
        sorted_nums = nums.copy()
        sorted_nums.sort()

        # To find the answer.
        for i,v in enumerate(sorted_nums):
        
            remaining = target - v
            if self.bisection(
                array=sorted_nums[i+1:], 
                target=remaining):

                # If the remaining is found in the rest of the list, 
                # then end the for loop by returning the answer index.
                return [nums.index(v), nums.index(remaining)]
    
    def bisection(self, array: List[int], target: int) -> bool:

        if len(array) < 1:
            return False
        # Only one element in array.
        # If it matches the target, return True.
        elif len(array) == 1:
            return (array[0] == target)

        # Multiple elements in array.
        # Determine the index of the median.
        if len(array) % 2 != 0:
            mid_index = len(array) // 2 + 1
        else:
            mid_index = len(array) // 2
        # If the median matches the target, return True.
        if array[mid_index] == target:
            return True
        # If the median is less than the target, use the right part of the array to locate the target.
        elif array[mid_index] < target:
            return self.bisection(self, array = array[mid_index + 1:], target = target)
        # If more than the target, use the left part to locate the target.
        else:
            return self.bisection(self, array = array[: mid_index], target = target)
# @lc code=end
```

The error message is as follows.

```
Line 44: TypeError: bisection() got multiple values for argument 'array'
TypeError: bisection() got multiple values for argument 'array'
    return self.bisection(self, array = array[: mid_index], target = target)
Line 44 in bisection (Solution.py)
    if self.bisection(
Line 13 in twoSum (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().twoSum(param_1, param_2)
Line 70 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 81 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't seem to match the code you posted. Where is the binary_search function?

Comment: `self.bisection(self, array = array[mid_index + 1:], target = target)` is attempting to pass `array` twice since you have an extra `self` argument. `self.bisection` already passes `self` as an argument implicitly. Get rid of the `self` in the argument list.

Comment: Sorry for that, I repost my question.

Comment: Thank you Carcigenicate, I've solved the problem with your help.

Answer (score 0):

`self.bisection(self, array = array[mid_index + 1:], target = target)` is attempting to pass `array` twice since you have an extra `self` argument. `self.bisection` already passes self as an argument implicitly. Get rid of the `self` in the argument list.

Answers from Carcigenicate.